# dialout group and serialport permission

Tags: permissions, serial-port

I faced a strange problem today.
I can't open my serial port and it says permission denied!!
It's strange because I checked and I member of the dialout group!
I'm using arduino.

Comment: Could you add `ls -l /dev/tty*` to the question. I expect that arduino port is created in `root` group not `dialout` by default.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's always helpful to write out all the commands and their results.

For Arduino in particular, what does this command return?

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

If it indicates less permission, you might want to give yourself read and write access, e.g.:

```
sudo chmod 600 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: To thoever downvoted; it'll be always helpful to improve (future) answeres and visitors if you leave comments why you had to downvote. Thanks.